# How to terminate a session scoped bean in JSF

Tags: java, session, jsf, jsf-2.2, java-ee-7

I have a page called `new.xhtml` it operate on a sessionScoped Bean called `New`. After some opeartions I need To terminate the bean, and start a new One when the user visits again new.xhml . How Can I do That??

Comment: In a class where it is 'injected', just do a 'new' on the field...  Try

Comment: @Kukeltje I think it won't overwrite its other injections. so there would be multiple instances there, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `httpSessionObj.removeAttribute("YOUR_BEAN_KEY")` to remove any session scoped bean. You can refer API [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#removeAttribute(java.lang.String)) on this.